# Can't print invoice after edited Currency file on Magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7, invoice

I have modified Currency file (app/code/local/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php) in order to show price with superscript decimals.

Everything was fine but i can't print invoices anymore.
Can you help me fix that problem? Thank you!

This is what I have modified:

I have replaced this function:

```
public function formatTxt($price, $options = array())
{
    if (!is_numeric($price)) {
        $price = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getNumber($price);
    }
    /**
     * Fix problem with 12 000 000, 1 200 000
     *
     * %f - the argument is treated as a float, and presented as a floating-point number (locale aware).
     * %F - the argument is treated as a float, and presented as a floating-point number (non-locale aware).
     */
    $price = sprintf("%F", $price);
    if ($price == -0) {
        $price = 0;
    }
    return Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency($this->getCode())->toCurrency($price, $options);
}
```

With this one:

```
public function formatTxt($price, $options = array())
{
    if (!is_numeric($price)) {
        $price = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getNumber($price);
    }
    /**
     * Fix problem with 12 000 000, 1 200 000
     *
     * %f - the argument is treated as a float, and presented as a floating-point number (locale aware).
     * %F - the argument is treated as a float, and presented as a floating-point number (non-locale aware).
     */
    $price = sprintf("%0.2f", $price); 
    $parts = explode('.', $price);
    if ($price == -0) {
        $price = 0;
    }       
    echo "$parts[0]<span style = 'white-space: nowrap; font-color: #ff0000;font-size:12px'><sup> ,$parts[1] USD</sup></span>";
}
```

Comment: Check the file for PHP errors via CLI with php -l app/code/local/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The invoices are in PDF format, HTML code is not going to help that.

This extension works nicely:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/et-currency-manager.html

With it you can do things like not show '.00'. I am sure you can adapt it to your needs. Give it a go.

For the invoices it is not necessary to have fancy formatting on the prices. The above extension does not affect how those are rendered.

Comment: Thank you! Edited that extension and problem was solved :)